# Automapper and dealing with null properties

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I've set my mapping up as follows:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>().ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => src.Providers.FirstOrDefault()));
```

Where I'm mapping from a List in my SourceClass to a string in my destination class.

My question is, how can I handle the case where "Providers" is null?

I've tried using:

`src?.Providers?.FirstOrDefault()`

but I get an error saying I can't use null propagators in a lambda.

I've been reading up on Automapper and am still unsure if AM automatically handles the null case or not. I tried to build the expression tree, but was not able to see any information that provided additional informations.

If it helps, I'm using automapper v 6.1.1.

Comment: Surely you can write some unit tests to see what happens.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu you're right, I will do that now

Comment: Not able to test this right now, but you could try `src?.Providers?.FirstOrDefault() ?? ""`. This sets the value to an empty string if the expression proceeding `??` evaluates to null.

Comment: @TylerHundley

So I added a unit test, and if Providers is null, it maps to null. Do you know how I'd be able to map an empty list to an empty list? As of now, I believe it is mapping an empty list to null (because of FirstOrDefault)

Comment: Do you mean map an empty list to an empty string? A null list to an empty string? Have you tried the code in my previous comment?

Comment: I did, but I got the same error about null propagators. What I'm trying to do now is modify my mapping. I don't know if you remember, but I used the mapping you had provided:

```CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
  .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Providers,
  memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => new List<string> {src.Provider ?? ""}));```

However, I want to modify it so that it maps to either a List<string> or an empty list instead of a list with an empty string.

Comment: Expression trees haven't been updated with any syntax additions since C# 3.0 or so. Get rid of the `?.` operators and write it as a `? :` expression instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a [ValueConverter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-converters.html) with AutoMapper. That might look something like this

```
public class ListFormatter : IValueConverter<string, List<string>>
{
  public List<string> Convert(string source)
  {
    if (source != null)
    {
      return new List<string> { source };
    }
    return new List<string>();
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
  .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
             memberOptions => memberOptions.ConvertUsing(new ListFormatter()));
```

This would allow you to change your value converter in the future if you need to switch logic or do something more complex.

**Edit**

Since you are using an older version, you could use a private/static/extension method to do the same thing. So something like

```
List<string> ConvertStringToList(string source)
{
  if (source != null)
  {
    return new List<string> { source };
  }
  return new List<string>();
}
```

and then call it like so

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
  .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
             memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => ConvertStringToList(src.Provider)));
```

I generally prefer this to doing something inline as things get more complex, for the sake of readability

Comment: Ah I spoke too soon, it seems as if the version of automapper we are using doesn't support ValueConverters

Comment: I also noticed you asked another question. Reading back over the comments in here I can't tell if you're asking about source to destination or destination to source conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use NullSubstitution option from AutoMapper
you can read [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Null-substitution.html)